# Test data source in MBUnit like in NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, mbunit

How can I annotate my MBUnit test with a test data source attribute like in NUnit:

Pseudocode like its in NUnit:

```
[TestCaseSource("GetData")]
public void Test(int value)
{

}

private static IEnumerable<int> GetData()
{
   yield return 1;
   yield return 2;
   yield return 3;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MbUnit supports a variety of test data sources using attributes.
Refer to [MBUnit documentation wiki](http://www.gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3aattributes).

Your NUnit example can be reimplemented in MBUnit using following syntax:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SampleFixture
{
  public IEnumerable<int> GetData()
  {
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
  }

  [Test, Factory("GetData")]
  public void Test(int value)
  {
  }
}
```